# Is there a natural extension of Levi-Civita connection to include torsion?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, connections

The Levi-Civity connection described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection specifically for torsion-free. The question is: do we have connection on the tangent bundle which takes into account torsion as well. The inclusion of torsion may be in terms of a parameter. I am looking for some reference to understand what is involve to do so.

**Motivation**: I am looking at Ricci flow. The project I have seems to require a solution of Ricci flow equations. The document in the link [https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nsher/ricciflow.pdf](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Ensher/ricciflow.pdf) explains quite a bit to derive the Ricci flow equation using Levi-Civity connection. But the project that I have, requires torsion to take into account.

Comment: Yes, there is a study of general connections, with or withouth torsion. Depending on the context, the natural connection to consider can have torsion: for example, in CR geometry, the Tanaka-Webster connection has torsion.

Comment: @Didier Thank you. I will read about it, Now I have realized that I did not mention in the question that our manifold is Riemannian. I hope not mentioning Riemannian is ok. I am looking for a method to create a trajectory in Riemannian manifold and I need to have scaling factor and torsion factor (if it works like that).

Comment: Another example is the Chern-ricci flow, which uses the Chern connection instead of the levi-civita connection. As Didier suggests, in some soecial geometries it is more important to choose connection that respect the special structure.